# Hook-length identity in terms of rational functions

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, integer-partitions

This comes from I. G. MacDonald's book *Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials*:

[image]

(1.7'): Put $f_{\lambda,n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}t^{\lambda_j+n-j}$, then
$$
f_{\lambda,n}(t)+t^{m+n-1}f_{\lambda',m}(t^{-1})=(1-t^{m+n})/(1-t)
$$
where $m \geq \lambda_1$, $n \geq \lambda_1'$. If $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots)$ is a partition, then $\lambda'=(\lambda'_1,\cdots)$ is its conjugate where $\lambda'_i=|\{j:\lambda_j \geq i\}|$

I'm OK with how he derived (2) but why does (2) also implie (3)? For him it seemed to be so trivial but I guess not for everyone, although I think the calculation shouldn't be tedious.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but there is a very slick direct proof of (3) in Volume 2 of Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics* (Lemma 7.21.1, formula (7.101)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation (2) is such that the multiset of terms for each sum on the left side have a matching term on the right side. All of those terms are transformed by $t^\square \mapsto (1 - t^\square)$, so that the matching of left-side terms and right-side terms remains. The equation

$$\prod_{x \in \lambda} \left(1 - t^{h(x)}\right) \cdot \prod_{i < j} \left(1 - t^{\mu_i - \mu_j}\right) = \prod_{i \geq 1} \prod_{j=1}^{\mu_i} \left(1 - t^j\right)$$

follows by matching the factors on the left side with the right in the same manner as the sums in (2).